# Dummy variable and negative estimation in GARCH (1.1)

Tags: garch

I am trying to use GARCH model for my research. However, when I am running them, I see negative value for alpha and beta. How I can restrict them so that they do not provide me any negative value. Is there any specific code for this? I follow the code arch var2, arch(1) garch(1). I also like to know, how to generate dummy variable in stata (code please).

Thanks,